# I get empty spaces where the components should been located

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, aura-if

### code

```
<aura:component controller="ProductController" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

    <aura:attribute name="soqlRequest" type="String" default="none" access="global"/>
    <aura:attribute name="listProducts" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="offset" type="Integer" default="0" />
    <aura:attribute name="allProductSOQL" type="String" default=" SELECT Name,AirRegulator__c,AmountReview__c,BatteryCapacity__c,ChargingTime__c,Length__c,NumberUnits__c,Rating__c,TankSize__c,(SELECT Product2Id,UnitPrice FROM PricebookEntries) FROM Product2 LIMIT 4 " />

    <aura:attribute name="soqlProcessing" type="Boolean" default="false" />

    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.soqlRequest}" action="{!c.updateSOQLRequestHandler}" />
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}" />

    <div class="slds-scrollable" aura:id="scrollContainer">
        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true" class="layoutClass">
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.listProducts}" var="itemProduct" indexVar="index">
                <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="12" smallDeviceSize="6" mediumDeviceSize="6" class="layoutItemClass">
                    <aura:If isTrue="{!itemProduct.PricebookEntries[0].UnitPrice != NULL }">
                        <c:ElectronicCigaretteCardComponent product="{!itemProduct}"/>                      
                    </aura:If>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

I don't want to display products with an empty price and so I use,but I get empty spaces where the components that were not displayed should have been located.How can I avoid this(empty spaces)?

Comment: did you try putting lightning:layoutItem inside aura if

Comment: ahaha).Thank you very much it help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put lightning:layoutItem inside your aura:if to remove empty spaces it will stop creating div unless the condition becomes true

```
 <aura:If isTrue="{!itemProduct.PricebookEntries[0].UnitPrice != NULL }">
 <lightning:layoutItem padding="around-large" size="12" smallDeviceSize="6" mediumDeviceSize="6" class="layoutItemClass">
<c:ElectronicCigaretteCardComponent product="{!itemProduct}"/> 
</lightning:layoutItem>
</aura:If>
```